# What is the best way to handle a camera raycast weakness in Unity 3rd person shooting?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 3rd person shooting. Camera raycast weakness

[image]

I use Raycast, camera.transform, camera.transform.forward but it occurs picture situation
how can i fix it?

i can fix it using RaycastAll, if hit.point is in between player and camera, ignore that hit point and get use next hit.point but i think this way is bad for optimization so i want find other way

Comment: Are you famiiar with the "layers" (physic layers) concepts in Unity ?

Comment: Just for clarity, there is no weakness (I guess you meant a problem or bug?) in PhysX, it works perfectly mathematically as you'd expect.

Comment: Finally do note that your optimization idea is out by a factor of 10,000 to 100,000. It's absolutely trivial to cycle through two or three hits.  Note that merely - say - rendering any random text you have on the scene would use 10s of thousands of times more processing power than what you're mentioning.  Ditto the mesh engine, rendering engine, etc.  All of that utterly dwarfs the tiny amount of processing power you're mentioning.  Again, I believe **physics layers** may be what you're looking for, possibly? Hope it helps

Comment: soryy my explane is bad, i want shoot the target and player watch the target but shoot the object between player and camera,

Comment: Id suggest taking the direction nof the camera but moving the distance of camera to player along it before testing the raycast

Comment: @BugFinder  the OP is just looking for the "layers" system which I guess he has not yet stumbled on to.

Comment: Unless that mystery object is also a potentially normal target.  Never hurts to have more ideas

Comment: @BugFinder YESSSS object infront of camera is target too, i kwow layer mask in raycast but layer mask is not solve my problem

Comment: So. Take the direction of your camera. Move forward the distance from camera to player and raycast from there.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the **layer system** in Unity physics.

It exists for precisely this reason, it's exactly how all physics works in games. It's the same in all game engines, not just unity.

https://docs.unity.cn/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

There are a million articles about this online, it's not really possible to "give you an answer" here to entirely explain the layer system.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1108781/set-ray-only-when-raycast-a-specific-layer.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo8tByZIQ3k

Just google "tutorial, Unity raycast layers" and you will find many beginner articles.

Also simply search "raycast layer Unity" on SO for 100s of articles about it.